# Make js-code work to add - remove a class in TYPO3 TS menu

Tags: jquery, typo3, zurb-foundation, typo3-9.x

I like to achieve this effect for a TYPO3 site navigation - see the codepen here:

https://codepen.io/mr_vespa/pen/zYryZQo

On load the menu has the first tab highlighted. On click the selected tab will be highlighted.
Both effects are not taking place.

1. How to get an "active" class on the first menu tab only
2. why is the js-code not applied
   both jquery and the js-code are included/
   TYPO3 version 9.*

The menu code (which is coded for use with Foundation 6.4.2 dropdown menu). and working fine.

```
    lib.nav_main = COA
lib.nav_main {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        #wrap = <div class="top-bar-right">|</div>
        entryLevel = 0
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            noBlur = 1
            wrap = <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>|</ul>
            target = _top
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-submenu">|</li>
                #allWrap = <div class=" ">|</div>
            }
            ACT <.NO
            ACT{
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-submenu">|</li>
        }
        }
        2 = TMENU
        2 {
            expAll = 1
            noBlur = 1
            wrap = <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>|</ul>
            target = _top
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-submenu">|</li>
                #allWrap = <div class=" ">|</div>
            }
            ACT <.NO
            ACT{
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-submenu">|</li>
        }
        }
        3 = TMENU
        3 {
            noBlur = 1
            wrap = <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>|</ul>
            target = _top
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-submenu">|</li>
                #allWrap = <div class=" ">|</div>
            }
               
                }
     
        }
        }
```

Comment: First, create a working menu as static HTML page, then use TypoScript to make it dynamic. We don't know which part of your code is problematic, HTML, JS, CSS or TypoScript. you need to find it yourself.

Comment: have you noticed that the highlighting of your HTML looks broken around `data-submenu`? I suppose some faulty quotes, which might confuse your javascript.

Comment: the html is working (have been a static html as you can see in the codepen). The js is a new option i'd like to add on request.  
@BerndWilkeπφ I will look into that. Strange thing is that it works as "static html but not when it is in the TYPO3 template.

Comment: look at your HTML wrap at `2` and `3`: `<ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu">|</ul>` there is an extra quote after `data-submenu`. I don't know how your browser will interpret it, but it might be false and result in other HTML than your static.

Comment: Any idea on the first question: How to get an "active" class on the first menu tab only in the TS-script menu I posted? I do not have an <a> tag where an class would go. And I only want the tag "active" only on the first menu item.

Comment: while using TYPO3 9  is better to use the DataProssesor to create your Menus. I have created a responsive foundation navigation if yu wanna take a look. Do you want me to add it on the answers?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas Yes please share. I am always interested in learning new ways of doing things in TYPO3 :) and with foundation.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the `MenuProcessor` with TYPO3 9 or higher. It is very easy and extremely flexible. The first step is to let TYPO3 9 know which Pages should process. A basic example.

**On your** `page = PAGE` **typoscript**:

```
page = PAGE
page {
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
       template = FILE
       template.file = EXT:yourExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/index.html
       partialRootPath = EXT:yourExtension/Resources/Private/Partials/
       layoutRootPath =  EXT:yourExtension/Resources/Private/Layouts/

       7000 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
       7000 {
         levels = 3
         includeSpacer = 1
         entryLevel = 0
         as = mainnavigation
       }
    }
 }
```

What this does, is to call the `MenuProcessor` and it makes a database request based on the arguments you defined. The arguments in this example:

- includeSpacer = Includes the "Spacer" type in the menus
- levels = How many levels should the Menuprocessor look for
- entryLevel = From which level should start. 0 means root page and so on
- as = is the variable that will be passed in the FrondEnd with the results of the `MenuProcessor`

**Your HTML** (Maybe on your Layouts?)

You will have to play around with the templates in order to get your desire result. Here is an example. Not 100% tested but it should work.

**Layouts:**

```
<f:render partial="Menu/MainNavigation" arguments={_all} />
```

Just calling the Menu partial

**Partials** (Menu/MainNavigation.html)

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="responsive_nav" data-hide-for="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="responsive_nav"></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div id="responsive_nav" class="top-bar">
   <div class="top-bar-left">
        <a class="title_bar_logo" href="{f:uri.page(pageUid:1)}">
            <f:image src="fileadmin/logo.svg" class="hide-for-small-only"/>
        </a>
   </div>
   <div class="top-bar-left">
     <f:render partial="Menu/Render/List" arguments="{
            records : mainnavigation,
            class   : 'dropdown menu',
            settings: settings,
            isFirstLevel : 1
        }"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Creating the default schema of the foundation navigation. After that we call the list partial. What we do is to call the list every time the `MenuProcessor` finds a submenu. Meaning that every time that a menu item has children, then the list partial will be called. So we do not have to manually write 10 levels of HTML.

**Partials** (Menu/Render/List.html)

```
<ul class="class="{class}" {f:if(condition:'{isFirstLevel} == 1', then: 'data-dropdown-menu', else: '')}">
    <f:for each="{records}" as="item" iteration="i">
        <f:render partial="Menu/Render/Item" arguments="{
            item    : item,
            settings: settings
        }"/>
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

Here we create the list schema and we call the children (`<li>` items).

**Partials** (Menu/Render/Item.html)

```
<f:variable name="_classActive" value="{f:if(condition:'{item.active} == 1', then: 'active', else: '')}"/>

<li class="nav__item {_classActive}">
    <a href="{item.link}" target="{item.target}" title="{item.title}">
        {item.title}
    </a>
   <f:if condition="{item.children->f:count()} > 0">
        <f:render partial="Menu/Render/List" arguments="{
            records : item.children,
            settings: settings,
            class: 'menu vertical'
        }"/>
   </f:if>
</li>
```

Here we create the `<li>` schema and we call the list if this menu item has a submenu.

Helpful Links:

- [Inroduction to MenuProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.5/Feature-78672-IntroduceFluidDataProcessorForMenus.html)
- [various Processors](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing)
- [Foundation Framework extension (soon to be updated for TYPO3 10)](https://github.com/AKaravas/foundation_zurb_framework/)

For any question, dont hesitate to ask.

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks good example I will try to work this out. Bit complicated at first sight but I can see the benefits of doing it this way. Will the TS menu as I now have still be valid and useful in future or will the MenuProcessor be the only way of doing things in TYPO3?