# How can I add a wrapping div tag to the a tag of the button in my menu of TYPO3 site?

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I have a header menu which contain a button and which is backend manageable. Following is the Typoscript for the menu button part.

```
50 = RECORDS
    50 {
        source.data = field:pid
        tables = pages
        conf.pages = TEXT
        conf.pages.field = teaserlinktext
        wrap =  <div class="menu-link">|<span class="submenu-arrow"></span></div>
        wrap.insertData = 1
        stdWrap.typolink {
          parameter.field = pid
          section.field = teaserlink
          teaserlink {
             cObject = RECORDS
             cObject {
                tables = pages
                source.data = field:teaserlink
                conf.pages = TEXT
                conf.pages.field = teaserlink
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

And this produce the output as :

```
<a href="/example/">
   <div class="menu-link">Übersicht<span class="submenu-arrow"></span></div>
</a>
```

But I actually want to take the div outside of the a tag as like the following:

```
<div class="menu-link">
   <a href="/example/">Übersicht</a>
   <span class="submenu-arrow"></span>
</div>
```

How to do this? Anyone pls help me..

Thanks!!

Comment: which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using 10.4.7

Comment: why dont you use the MenuProcessor? This way you get everything in FLUID and you can do whatever you want :)

Comment: here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058177/make-js-code-work-to-add-remove-a-class-in-typo3-ts-menu/63070274#63070274

Comment: Thanks Aristeidis Karavas, I will try, but this is urgent :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I got the answer.

```
50 = RECORDS
    50 {
        source.data = field:pid
        tables = pages
        conf.pages = TEXT
        conf.pages.field = teaserlinktext
        stdWrap.typolink {
          parameter.field = pid
          section.field = teaserlink
          teaserlink {
             cObject = RECORDS
             cObject {
                tables = pages
                source.data = field:teaserlink
                conf.pages = TEXT
                conf.pages.field = teaserlink
             }
          }
       }
       stdWrap.wrap =  <div class="menu-link">|<span class="submenu-arrow"></span></div>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `outerWrap.` instead of `wrap`.
Then your wrap will be outside.

As Aristeidis mentioned, you should use a DataProcessor. Then you can do the HTML and wrapping stuff easily in your template directly instead of TypoScript.

Resources:

- wrap and outerWrap: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html
- DataProcessing: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried this already. this time the div disappeared and only 'a' tag is there.    :) I will try the data processor on the next time.

Answer (score 0):

a good overview about the hierarchy of wraps for menu items and normal text can you find [here](https://jweiland.net/typo3/beispiele-anleitungen-faq/typoscript/wrap-moeglichkeiten-und-hierarchie-in-menues.html)